# Is this a correct translation of "Destruction ain't a crime for those who find love as a game"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

English: "Destruction ain't a crime for those who find love as a game"

Latin: "Exitium nōn scelus est prō illīs qui amōrem lūsus esse putant."

.

Salvete, omnes! I'm currently translating a song from English to Latin and I've come up with a line I'm having a little bit of trouble with, so I was wondering if anyone could tell me if it is correct grammatically speaking. Certainly it can't be a direct translation, I figured out that what the Latin sentence ended up saying is something closer to: "Destruction is not a crime for those who think love is a game". But I am very much okay with that.

In advance, thank you!
Btw, the song is "Dear Boy" by Avicii.

Comment: I just googled and I think the English sentence in the song is "Destruction ain't a crime for those who find love _is_ a game like you and I." Some web sites have _as_ but that appears to be an error. _As_ instead of _is_ isn't ungrammatical, but it's not how to express what appears to be the meaning: "…for those who find [that] love is a game like you and I."

Answer (score 4):

*Lūsus* needs to be *lūsum* to agree with *amōrem.*

I think the sense of "for" in the sentence is normally rendered by the dative in Latin. *Scelus prō aliquō* is a crime committed on behalf of someone, not a crime in the eyes of someone.

Other than that, your translation is correct. I'm also only a beginner, though, so you should await another answer or a confirmation from someone more knowledgeable.

I made an attempt to follow my own corrections and came up with this, which might passably fit the melody:

> Dulcis mī care
> exitium illīs decet
> quī amōrem lūsum putant
> ut tibi et mihi.

I replaced *nōn scelus est* with *decet* to exploit a strength of Latin: a verb often carries a meaning more strongly than a noun with *est,* and *decet* goes nicely with the dative. Also, especially in a song, you can omit *esse* with *putant.*

Comment: Perhaps one might also say *putent* (“such people who,” subjunctive of characteristic).

Comment: Thank you very much! So it would have a sense closer to "Destructium is suitable for those who find love as a game", wouldn't it? Again I appreciate your comment so much.

Comment: @DiegoOjeda Yes. I find _decet_ impossible to translate into English. Let's just say that it means the opposite of a crime: something proper, dignified, honorable. The English word "decent" comes from _decet._

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: What do you think about the subjunctive-of-characteristic, here?